# Decode json nested PHP (laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel

Sorry if this is rookie standard. The nesting really confuses me. Code here:

```
$json= '[{ "all":
 "{"data":
 [ {"name": "Kofi", "age":13}, {"name": "Jay", "age":17} ]
}"
}]' ;

$decode = json_decode($json);
$names= $decode->all->data->name;

// I want to retrieve "Kofi" and "Jay"

foreach ($names as $name){
echo $name;
}
```

I want to retrieve 
    Kofi, Jay
I get the error: 
    Trying to get property 'all' of non-object

Comment: You have an array of one object. That one object has one key, `all` whose value is a _string of JSON data_. You need to decode the outer array, then decode the value of the `all` key.

Comment: try with `$decode[0]->all->data[0]->name;` and `$decode[0]->all->data[1]->name;`

Comment: Tried that. Didnt work. Same error: trying to get property 'all' of non-object. Thanks though.

Comment: You want to convert the json to ? a php associative array ?

Comment: Not really, i just want to return names in the array in plain. Like "Kofi", "Jay". Hope you get it. But I'm up for corrections and suggestions too.

Comment: if you lost in the hierarchy, `print_r($decode)` or `var_dump($decode)` to the rescue...

Comment: your json is not correct... is not a valid json

Comment: print_r var_dump couldn't do they rescue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your json, it wasn't formatted properly. I have formatted it and this extra bit of code should do the job for you.

NOTE: The only difference was `"all": "{"...."}"` changed to `"all": { .... }`

```
    $json= '[
            {
                "all":
                    {
                        "data":
                                [ 
                                    { "name": "Kofi", "age":13}, 
                                    {"name": "Jay", "age":17} 
                                ]
                    }
            }
        ]';

    $decode = json_decode($json);

    foreach($decode[0]->all->data as $dec) {
        echo $dec->name. '<br/>';
    }
```